# T-SQL to generate list of renewal dates based on single upcoming date and renewal term

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked to create a report that will show the renewal date for every account package based on a single renewal date and the renewal term. This report should show all the renewal dates up to the end of December 2018.

All account packages have a term in months (1 to 12) and the current renewal date (next one coming up) (AccountPackage table).

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| AccountPkgID | PkgTermMonths | RenewalDate  |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|            1 |             1 | 12/1/2015    |
|            2 |             3 | 12/1/2015    |
|            3 |             6 | 12/1/2015    |
|            4 |            12 | 12/1/2015    |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I was able to handle all monthly packages by doing a Cartesian product of package table with a table of all the months (Report_MonthlyDates table).

```
+----------------+
| dtfirstofmonth |
+----------------+
| 12/1/2015      |
| 1/1/2016       |
| 2/1/2016       |
| 3/1/2016       |
| . each month . |
| 12/1/2018      |
+----------------+
```

Here is the SQL I came up with below that worked for only 1 month packages… the 3 month or greater didn’t work.

```
SELECT AllPkgs.AccountPkgID, AllPkgs.PkgTermMonths, MonthlyPkgs.dtfirstofmonth
from
(SELECT AccountPkgID,  PkgTermMonths, RenewalDate
FROM Accountpackage 
WHERE RenewalDate >= '12/1/2015' 
AND RenewalDate < '1/1/2019') AllPkgs
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT dtfirstofmonth 
FROM [Report_MonthlyDates] 
WHERE dtfirstofmonth >= '12/1/2015' 
AND dtfirstofmonth < '1/1/2019') MonthlyPkgs ON (AllPkgs.months = 1)
```

The only other idea I came up with was a cursor, but it will have horrible performance. I would love to be able to do it with a table function or something.

The output that I would like to get:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| AccountPkgID |  RenewalDate    |
+--------------+-----------------+
|            1 | 12/1/2015       |
|            1 | 1/1/2016        |
|            1 | … every month … |
|            1 | 12/1/2018       |
|            2 | 12/1/2015       |
|            2 | 3/1/2016        |
|            2 | 6/1/2016        |
|            2 | 9/1/2016        |
|            2 | 12/1/2016       |
|            2 | 3/1/2017        |
|            2 | 6/1/2017        |
|            2 | 9/1/2017        |
|            2 | 12/1/2017       |
|            2 | 3/1/2018        |
|            2 | 6/1/2018        |
|            2 | 9/1/2018        |
|            2 | 12/1/2018       |
|            3 | 12/1/2015       |
|            3 | 6/1/2016        |
|            3 | 12/1/2016       |
|            3 | 6/1/2017        |
|            3 | 12/1/2017       |
|            3 | 6/1/2018        |
|            3 | 12/1/2018       |
|            4 | 12/1/2015       |
|            4 | 12/1/2016       |
|            4 | 12/1/2017       |
|            4 | 12/1/2018       |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Any ideas would be a huge help.

Comment: Please edit your question and show what results you want to get.

Comment: I updated the question with the results I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to need a numbers table.  Once we construct that, the rest is just some SQL:

```
with numbers as (
      select n.*
      from (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n -- starts at 0
            from master..spt_values
           ) n
      where n < 100 -- 100 values should be quite sufficient for the end of 2018
     )
select ap.AccountPkgID,
       dateadd(month, n.n  * ap.PkgTermMonths, ap.renewaldate) as renewaldate
from AccountPackage ap join
     numbers n
     on dateadd(month, n.n * ap.PkgTermMonths, ap.renewaldate) <= '2018-12-31'
order by AccountPkgID, n.n;
```

Comment: This was great. There was only one minor change I made to make it increment by term (3 month or 6 month). 

select ap.AccountPkgID, dateadd(month, PkgTermMonths * n.n, ap.renewaldate) as renewaldate

Comment: @Dave . . . I fixed that.